# How to get current language of node in twig?

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

I have a tranlatable node, and I need to get its translation language. You know, I must to know is current node is in Polish or English. So... below there are my devel dumps from a node in Polish and a node in English. I see that there is a difference in `#activeLangcode` (x-default and en). But how to get that value? Or is there any better way to check current language of node in twig? Please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can do this with a hook_preprocess_node. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186520/drupal-8-and-twig-get-language

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more elegant Drupal way without typing code:

1. Go to the Manage display of the content type of your node (/admin/structure/types/manage/YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE/display/full). Select your display mode (or use the default). You will notice the field 'Language', move it to the upper side so it gets out of 'Disabled'.
2. Once you have done that, the language of the node is available in Twig. You can access the id this way `{{ node.langcode.langcode }}`; or you can access the whole Object to get other data like the name `{{ drupal_dump(node.langcode) }}`

Comment: This is the only simple way to get the langcode in <D 10. What a horrible desaster. Shouldn't be that complicated to get it right from the entity. However, thank you so much!

Comment: finally found an answer that fits Drupal 10. thanks